# code on erlang. how refer to real sftp and copy file to my directory

Tags: erlang

i'm new in Erlang.
Tell me how to refer to sftp and copy the file using the erlang code.
Can anyone have a link to a resource with similar examples or documentation?
Thanks!

Comment: Here is the "Getting started" page from the ssh application user's guide: https://erlang.org/doc/apps/ssh/using_ssh.html

Comment: can there be a real example of how to use this? it is not entirely clear where the user is, specify the address and password

Comment: what behavior or library must be used for these functions to work in a module?

Answer (score 1):

```erlang
Host = "...". %% remote host
Port = 22. %% port
Options = [{user, "..."}, %% ssh remote user
           {silently_accept_hosts, true}, %% 
           {user_dir, "/path/to/.ssh"} %% ssh directory on local machine
          ].

RemoteFilePath = "". %% path to where you need to sftp local file
{ok, FileData} = file:read_file("/path/to/local/file").

%% connect to remote host
{ok, SshConnection} = ssh:connect(Host, Port, Options).

%% start sftp channel
{ok, Channel} = ssh_sftp:start_channel(SshConnection).

%% ftp the file
ok = ssh_sftp:write_file(Channel, RemoteFilePath, FileData).

%% stop sftp channel
ssh_sftp:stop_channel(Channel).

%% close ssh connection
ssh:close(SshConnection).
```

For the code to work, you need to setup SSH access between the local machine and remote host using SSH keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
 I need it to work automatically. 
How to make the password be entered automatically? 
After
{ok, SshConnection} = ssh: connect (Host, Port, Options).
  the team asks for a password. I want to write this all in a module and make it work automatically.
 Add an extra field in options?
I do not find a similar case in the documentation(

Answer (score 0):

the issue was resolved.
Options = [{user, "..."}, {password, "..."},...]
Thank you all